# Replace text inside any <p> tag html with C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to replace any text that i have inside `<p>` tag, If i have the follow HTML:

```
<p><br />
<html><br />
<body></p>
<p><h1>My First JavaScript</h1></p>
<p><button type="button"<br />
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()"><br />
Click me to display Date and Time.</button></p>
<p><p id="demo"></p></p>
<p></body><br />
</html> <br />
</p>
</div>
```

I want to change any text that inside the `<p>` tag and replace the special characters, What I'm tried:

```
string pTag = "<p>";
        int pLength = pTag.Length;

        int index = input.IndexOf(pTag, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        while (index > 0)
        {
            int lastIndex = input.IndexOf("</p>", index);

            if (lastIndex == index)
                break;
            var subString = input.Substring(index + pLength, lastIndex - index - pLength);
            var newsubString = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(subString);
            input = input.Replace(subString, newsubString);

            index = lastIndex;
        }
```

But my code change only the first item,
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you get code like this `<p><p></p></p>` or some equally bad HTML? I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, not an answer, but I'd totally go JQUERY.

Comment: It`s better to work with the HTML via build in class instead of working with it like text ...

Comment: Use http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack or another HTML parser. Whether you use string manipulation or RegEx, you're not going to be able to accurately parse arbitrary HTML without a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting your `break;`

After you found your first tag and made your changes your say:

`index = lastIndex;`

The next time the loop starts and hits:

```
int lastIndex = input.IndexOf("</p>", index);
```

The same index will be hit and the break will exit the loop.

change to something like:

```
int lastIndex = input.IndexOf("</p>", index + 4);
```

and break whenever the IndexOf method returns -1 (indicating that it hasn't found and occurrence of the specified string)

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
        string html = "<p>oldtext</p>";
        string open = "<p>";
        string close = "</p>";
        int start = html.IndexOf(open);
        int end = html.IndexOf(close);
        string result = html.Substring(start + open.Length, end - (close.Length - 1));
        html = html.Replace(result, "newtext");
```